# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, shell, exec

Trying to run a cpp program through shell, using exec command in nodejs, I wrote below exec command in node.js. (btw i am trying in windows)

```
exec(`g++ ${fileData.filepath} -o ${outPath} && cd ${outputPath} && ./${jobId}.exe,
   (error,stdout,stderr)=>{
                if(error){
                    reject({error,stderr})
                }
                if(stderr){
                    reject(stderr)
                }
                resolve(stdout)
            })
```

The Program is getting stored where it was expected to get stored in .exe format. There is one error which I am getting which is **'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,   operable program or batch file.** Help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `./` from the exec command for executing the **exe** file, because **./** is used in linux, not in Windows ( When you are already in the directory containing the executable file ).

```
exec(`g++ ${fileData.filepath} -o ${outPath} && cd ${outputPath} && ${jobId}.exe`,
   (error,stdout,stderr) => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

For an executable you don't need to do `./` . just filename.exe should work.